# Help adding custom url, rewrite_rules_array

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to get a `rewrite_rules_array` rule to work and running into issues. I would like to add a rule so that when someone visits:

> http://domain.com/product/foo/bar

It essentially loads:

> http://domain.com/product/foo?view=bar

What really happens is that Wordpress redirects you to http://domain.com/product/foo.

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', function( $rules ) {
    $new = array();
    $new['product/(.*)/(.*)/?'] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&view=$matches[2]';
    return array_merge( $new, $rules );
});
```

- I've flushed my permalinks.
- `view` has been added to the query_vars.

Comment: Your products are pages of the `page` post type? Also- just use `add_rewrite_rule` hooked to `init` if you’re just adding rules and not manipulating existing rules or reordering.

Comment: @Milo They are of type 'product'.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking, the solution was:

```
add_action('init', function() {

     add_rewrite_rule(
        'product/(.*)/(.*)/?',
        'index.php?product=$matches[1]&view=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );

});
```